# pandas - aggregate part of column to new value in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large `pandas` dataframe `df` with warehouse data showing amounts of received items.

Imagine the relevant part of the structure as:

```
Date         SKU    received
2017-05-29   sku1   0
2017-05-30   sku1   0
2017-05-31   sku1   0
2017-06-01   sku1   0
2017-06-02   sku1   6
2017-06-03   sku1   2
2017-05-29   sku2   4
2017-05-30   sku2   4
2017-05-31   sku2   0
2017-06-01   sku2   0
2017-06-02   sku2   0
2017-06-03   sku2   24
```

From here I would like to reconstruct the order process. I know, that the stock level is reviewed on mondays, based on the stock level, new orders are placed. Orders arrive at the warehouse roughly a week later, sometimes split into multiple shippings.

I thought of creating an extra column for the weekdays (`df["Weekday"]`) and for the placed orders (`df["Order"]`). **Based on the weekday, I would like to aggregate the data of the "received" column for the next 4 to 11 days, restricted to the relevant SKU.**

The output could look like this:

```
Date         SKU    received    Weekday    Order
2017-05-29   sku1   0           0          8
2017-05-30   sku1   0           1          0
2017-05-31   sku1   0           2          0  
2017-06-01   sku1   0           3          0
2017-06-02   sku1   6           4          0
2017-06-03   sku1   2           5          0
2017-05-29   sku2   4           0          24
2017-05-30   sku2   4           1          0
2017-05-31   sku2   0           2          0
2017-06-01   sku2   0           3          0
2017-06-02   sku2   0           4          0
2017-06-03   sku2   24          5          0
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

# 0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, etc
df["Weekday"] = df["Date"].dt.dayofweek

# create new column for the orders
df["Order"] = 0

min_days = 4
max_days = min_days + 7

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, "Weekday"] == 0:
        df.loc[i, "Order"] = df.loc[(df.Date >= df.loc[i, "Date"] + pd.to_timedelta(min_days, unit="D")) &
                                    (df.Date < df.loc[i, "Date"] + pd.to_timedelta(max_days, unit="D")) &
                                    (df.SKU == df.loc[i, "SKU"]), "received"].sum()
```

It seems to do the job, but in a slow way. Maybe someone can help me find a more pythonic/pandas approach to save some computation time.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that uses pandas groupby and transform.

First idea is that you can achieve the count between two days by taking the difference of rolling sums. Also, note the trick of revert the order (`[::-1]`) twice in order to have a rolling sum picking days in the future.

```
def count_between(ts, min_days, max_days):
    return ts[::-1].pipe(lambda y: y.rolling(max_days,1).sum() - y.rolling(min_days-1,1).sum())[::-1]
```

This function would give you results for each day, so you restrict results to Mondays only setting all other entries to 0 (using `[.where][1]`).

After setting `Date` as index, you can do the following:

```
order = df.groupby('SKU')\
          .transform(lambda x: count_between(x, min_days, max_days)\
                               .where(lambda y: y.index.dayofweek==0, other = 0))
order.columns = ['Order']
```

This gives the expected result:

```
pd.concat([df, order], axis = 1)
Out[319]: 
             SKU  received  Order
Date                             
2017-05-29  sku1         0    8.0
2017-05-30  sku1         0    0.0
2017-05-31  sku1         0    0.0
2017-06-01  sku1         0    0.0
2017-06-02  sku1         6    0.0
2017-06-03  sku1         2    0.0
2017-05-29  sku2         4   24.0
2017-05-30  sku2         4    0.0
2017-05-31  sku2         0    0.0
2017-06-01  sku2         0    0.0
2017-06-02  sku2         0    0.0
2017-06-03  sku2        24    0.0
```

Comment: thanks @FLab. My `df` is in fact a bit larger and has more columns, `Date` is not the index, which is why I run into trouble running the code `y.index.dayofweek==0`.

Comment: Adapting the code to `count_between(x.received, min_days, max_days)` and `.where(lambda y: y.Date.dayofweek==0` does not help. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, yes, should have mentioned that I set Date as index. Can't you operate on a subset of the dataframe that looks like the reported example? In the meanwhile I will think to a fix

Comment: What if you define:

df = original_data[["Date", "SKU", "received"]].set_index('Date')

And then use the solution above? would that work?